# deadlock when using so built by go

Tags: go, shared-libraries, cgo, ld-preload

I've compiled a so file to use LD_PRELOAD. Deadlokc occurs when using the LD_PRELOAD so file

```
[golib]# LD_PRELOAD=`pwd`/libshellhook.so bash  grepconf.sh -c
<hang here>
```

When I use gdb to debug this, it's stack show:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fdf8d79a995 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fdf8e313723 in _cgo_wait_runtime_init_done () at gcc_libinit.c:40
#2  0x00007fdf8e313446 in execve (filename=0x1909350 "/usr/libexec/grepconf.sh", argv=0x1908b00, envp=0x1907d10) at _cgo_export.c:26
#3  0x000000000042fc02 in shell_execve ()

(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    Thread 0x7fdf8e856740 (LWP 25485) "bash" 0x00007fdf8d79a995 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

go version

```
$ go version
go version go1.14.9 linux/amd64
```

It works fine in fedora 32 and centos 6, but hangs in ubuntu 1804 and centos 7(3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64.debug )

Comment: This isn't the place to file Go issues. I find it more surprising that it ever worked reliably, since the runtime itself is inherently multi-threaded. I would suggest continuing in the go issue thread.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/43836   I post an issue here and add some comments.